# Issue while feeding a placeholder with shape (?, n)

Tags: python, tensorflow, placeholder

I've an issue to feed my placeholder. I have the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'NSregex_9/Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,30]
```

I feed my placeholder with a np.array of shape [1, 30]:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
     session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     regexp_vector = generate_tf_vector_from_list_regexp(NSinput, regexplist)
     regexp_vector = np.expand_dims(regexp_vector, axis=0)
     print("regexp_vector", regexp_vector, type(regexp_vector))

     session.run(tf.tables_initializer(), feed_dict={NSregex: regexp_vector})
     history = NSmodel.fit(input_train, 
        output_train,
        validation_data=(input_test, output_test),
        epochs=100,
        batch_size=32)
```

the output of generate_tf_vector_from_list_regexp(x, y) is a numpy array of size 30. Therefore I expand it with 1 more dimension to fit with my pleceholder shape.

So, I'm struggling to find a solution to feed correctly the placeholder. Every layers of my model have shape of (?, n). The question mark (?) should be assess according to the batch_size  ... I don't see where I'm wrong.

You could find below the code to give you the overall context:

```
def generate_tf_vector_from_list_regexp(s, listr):
    '''
    input is string tensor
    listr is a string list of regexp 
    '''
    v=[]
    for regexp in listr:
        if  tf.reshape(tf.strings.regex_full_match(s,tf.convert_to_tensor(regexp, dtype=tf.string)), [])==True:
            v.append(1.0)
        else:
            v.append(0.0)
    return np.asarray(v)
```

the regexEmbedding lamnda function is just a lambda fonction to create my placeHolder:

```
def RegexEmbedding(x):
    return = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, nb_classe])
```

and the model:

```
NSinput = layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.string, name='NSinput')
NSuse = layers.Lambda(UniversalEmbedding, output_shape=(embed_size,), name="NSuse")(NSinput)
NSregex = layers.Lambda(RegexEmbedding, input_shape=(1,), output_shape=(nb_classe,), name="NSregex")(NSinput)
NSconcat = layers.concatenate([NSuse, NSregex], axis=1)
NSdenseConcat = layers.Dense(256, input_shape=(dims,), activation='relu', name="NSdenseConcat")(NSconcat)
NSoutput = layers.Dense(nb_classe, activation='softmax', name="NSoutput")(NSdenseConcat)
NSmodel = Model(inputs=NSinput, outputs=NSoutput)
NSmodel.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
NSmodel.summary()
```

Many Thanks!!

Comment: The shape looks good. Are you sure `regexp_vector` contains floats? If you could provide enough code to reproduce the error, people will be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, I've add code in the description